# gsutil finding the uncompressed file size

Tags: gsutil

Is there a way to get the uncompressed file size using gsutils? I've looked into du and ls -l. Both return the compressed size. I would like to avoid having to download the files to see their size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gsutils provides only some basic commands like copy, list directory files etc. I would like to suggest you to write a python scripts which let you know the original size of the zipped files.